# It scrolls to the top of the page after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to switch a switching button image:

```
$("#invio_scatola_on, #invio_scatola_off").click(function(){
    $("#invio_scatola_off").toggle();
    $("#invio_scatola_on").toggle();
});
```

when it is executed, the browser goes to the top of the page. why?

Comment: Post the HTML for the buttons as well. Are there any `<a>` elements with `href="#"` ?

Comment: are there any elements at the top of the page with the same id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to prevent the default action of whatever element you click:

```
$("#invio_scatola_on, #invio_scatola_off").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#invio_scatola_off, #invio_scatola_on").toggle();
});
```

Comment: +1 for optimizing the code and using the latest jQuery magic with "on" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the few information that you've provided, if the browser is scrolling to the top, it means that you need to prevent its default behavior.

Check to see if the browser is **appending** "something" to the current URL...

**You can prevent that like this:**

```
$("#invio_scatola_on, #invio_scatola_off").click(function(event){

  // prvent default behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  $("#invio_scatola_off").toggle();
  $("#invio_scatola_on").toggle();
});
```

See the jQuery [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) for more information on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, because you didn't post your html code. Most probably your two elements are links with `href="#"`. After you click handler the regular action is fired, navigating to the anchor `#` on your site (which is the top).

Try:

```
$("#invio_scatola_on, #invio_scatola_off").click(function(event){
    $("#invio_scatola_off").toggle();
    $("#invio_scatola_on").toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and see if that helps. More on event cancelling with jQuery here:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1):

I think you **binded** the **click** on **anchor** tags with **href** as **#** so for that you can use **preventDefault()** of **javascript** like :

```
$("#invio_scatola_on, #invio_scatola_off").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#invio_scatola_off").toggle();
    $("#invio_scatola_on").toggle();
});
```